# Looping through Kotlin x times, but not using the index

Tags: kotlin

I want to loop through x times.

```
    for (i in 0 until x - 1) {
        // Do something.
    }
```

But I don't need to use the `i`. Is there a way better way to write the for-loop, without need to set the `i`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A [range](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) is iterable.  So to loop exactly `x` times, something like this would work:

```
(0 until x).forEach {
    // ...
}
```

An even simpler approach is this:

```
repeat(x) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that in both cases, the index is still accessible via the implicit `it` lambda parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
repeat(10) { _ ->
  println("Hello, world!")
}
```